# Tolerance on bolt major diameters

Tags: standards, tolerance

What are the tolerance specs on the major diameter of imperial bolts?

Specifically, a 1/4-20 imperial bolt has a major diameter of 0.25in, but what is the tolerance on that dimension. I (and everyone I've asked) have always taken that value to be exact, but that's obviously incorrect.

Comment: Thread only or shank?

Comment: Just the major diameter on the threads. I've found a few standards docs with tolerances on unthreaded shanks, but nothing on the threaded portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a screw thread chart.

http://www.engineersedge.com/screw_threads_chart.htm

Note there are different tolerance classes, and also note the max is never over the nominal size.

For the example 1/4-20

```
class 2: 0.2408 < d < 0.2489
class 3: 0.2419 < d < 0.25
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I find it a little interesting that the tolerances on the class two are both minus from the nominal dimension. I thought that was against ASME Y14.5 standard?

Comment: The nominal size is the minimum major diameter of the internal thread. (follow the link on that engineers edge page) The "class 2" is essentially a deliberately loose fit.

Comment: RIght! it's limit dimensions not tolerance dimensions, which makes sense. The loose fit makes sense.